# Generate test code from cucumber feature file

Tags: ruby, cucumber

Is it possible to generate test code from a cucumber feature file? Some developers prefer to read actual code instead of parsing the natural language and associated step definitions used by Cucumber.

Instead of (or as a side effect of) running cucumber a file with test code could be generated. E.g. the code that is inside the step definitions.

Comment: Somewhere you need to have a mapping from natural language to code.  The step definition files are serving that purpose.  You might look into Rspec feature specs.  They don't use `gerkin` but just ruby and the `rspec` dsl.  They serve the same purpose as cucumber - full integration testing - without the natural language parsing bit.   https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/feature-specs/feature-spec